# What tags are more popular at certain hours?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, statistics, popularity

I was looking at this question: [What is the best time to ask questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1313/what-is-the-best-time-to-ask-questions), and the thought that popped into my mind was, are certain tags more popular in certain countries than other tags?

For example, does the usage of the Java tag go up or down when it enters a particular timezone, say the West Coast? Looking on [Google Trends](http://google.com/trends), while searching for names of programming languages, I have noticed that India is usually the place with the most searches, but after that, it often varies, going to places such as Cuba and the Philippines. Are certain tags more preferred in the US?

Comment: I think data.stackexchange.com has the information you need - i.e. post time and tags used.

Comment: Related: [Which tags on SO are more popular during business days, which during weekends?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/46234) We love statistics around here.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a real-time system (well, not really); people find the questions when they log in.  What do you mean by "best time?" The time when you get the fastest possible response to your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you take the [java](/questions/tagged/java) tag the total number of post and comment actions can be obtained by [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/294244#graph) and the graph looks like this:

[image: java tag time distribution]

So for the java tag we can conclude that between 14:00 and 15:00 UTC is the time that you can expect most activity on posts/comments.

To analyze based on location is less easy because the location field is either empty or the Google geocoder breaks on *Somewhere on Earth* but nevertheless I created [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/294247/badges-per-location) that can be used as a starting point for the analysis. I only looked at java badgeholders here.

```
;with all_loc as (
select  u.location
, count(*) as per_country
from users u 
where u.location is not null
and u.location <> ''
group by u.location
)
, badge_loc as (
select  u.location
, count(*) as [badges]
from users u 
where exists (select 1 
              from badges 
              where userid = u.id 
              and name ='java')
and u.location is not null
 and u.location <>''
group by u.location 
)
select a.location
     , a.per_country
     , b.badges
     , cast(b.badges as decimal) 
     / cast(a.per_country as decimal) * 100 as perc
     , (select count(*) 
        from users 
        where location is not null
        and location <> '') as tot_count
from all_loc a
inner join badge_loc b on b.location = a.location
```